# Possible bug in lambda mutable reference capture optioning in GCC 5.2.0?

Tags: c++, g++

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/252266963e43652a

versus

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/838b3b45b25f577e

Why does it make a difference whether I say:

```
[&, data]() mutable {} vs. [&data]() mutable {}
```

Should it? Or should it not?

(The function that has the change is `append_data()`).

Comment: because they are not the same thing?

Comment: Also, may I ask what a mutable reference is?

Comment: @gnzlbg I wish I could delete this question :|

Comment: Top tip: when you assume it's a compiler bug, it's not; it's you being dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[&, data]` captures `data` by value and everything else by reference, whereas `[&data]` captures only `data` and captures it by reference.